# how to get integer back using pluck and not an array?

Tags: laravel

I have this

```
Model::where('menu_id', 'core.extensions')->pluck('id')
```

and it returns an array back, so I have to do this

```
Model::where('menu_id', 'core.extensions')->pluck('id')[0]);
```

to get the integer id I want and instert it directly. How can I get id back and avoid using [0] since it does not look elegant to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `value()` instead of `pluck()`. It will call `first()` on the query only selecting that column, and then just return the value:

```
$id = Model::where('menu_id', 'core.extensions')->value('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `first()`:

```
Model::where('menu_id', 'core.extensions')->first()->id;
```